# Kendo UI Grid template doesn't work in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: telerik-grid, kendo-ui, jqgrid

I have a Grid template in Kendo UI looking like the following:

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
<tr class="row-template">
    <td style="width:80px">
        <div rowspan="4"><img src="../../Images/picture_temp.jpg" class="display_searchresults_picture"/></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="display_searchresults_name"><a href="">#= FirstName # #= LastName # </a></div>
        <div align="right" width="100px">* * * * *(4.5)</div>                       
        # for (var i = 0; i < Education.length; i++) { #      
            <div class="display_searchresults_address">#= Address.City #, #= Address.State # | #= Education[i].School.Name #</div>         
            # for (var j = 0; j < Education[i].Major.length; j++) { #          
                <div class="display_searchresults_info">#= Education[i].Major[j].Name # | #= Education[i].GraduationDate.Year # | 3.5-3.75</div>              
            # } #
        # } #                                                                                         
        <div class="display_searchresults_desc" colspan="2">#= Description #<a href="">...</a></div>         
    </td>
</tr>
```

This template works like a charm in IE 9, but in Firefox it rendrers as:

```
#= FirstName # #= LastName #
* * * * *(4.5)
# for (var i = 0; i < Education.length; i++) { #
#= Address.City #, #= Address.State # | #= Education[i].School.Name #
# for (var j = 0; j < Education[i].Major.length; j++) { #
#= Education[i].Major[j].Name # | #= Education[i].GraduationDate.Year # | 3.5-3.75
# } # # } #
#= Description #...
```

Basically, it renders as code, not as html.

As for Chrome, the grid doesn't get rendered there at all. How can I make Kendo UI Grid template work for other browsers?

Answer (score 2):

Hello your template seems to be working fine. Here is it in action [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/edamuj/91/edit).

You can check the console to see if there are any JavaScript errors when you are using your data. If any of the fields like Education is not defined it might break the template.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. I was able to fix this not working in Firefox by referencing the Kendo libraries locally, not through the CDNs. Apparently, it wasn't loading fast enough through CDNs for Firefox. That's why some Kendo stuff wasn't getting referenced. But then it started throwing up an exception in IE: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'prototype': object is null or undefined". I had tried rearranging my references in every each way and nothing seemed to work.

Comment: When I included jQuery library along with Kendo UI library, I started getting errors stating that kendoMenu and kendoGrid were unrecognized. Finally, I had fixed my IE issue by dropping the reference to kendo.all.min.js and instead using kendo.web.min.js, which is what I need anyways. However, it still doesn't work in Chrome. So, I need to figure out why.

Comment: I had finally figured out the last piece. It turns out that the Kendo UI grid, which is essentially a <table> in HTML, doesn't always like to be inside other tables. The page I was working on was layed out as one giant table. That's not how I would design it, but that's how it was. Once I got rid of a table wrapping my Kendo UI Grid, it started working fine for all browsers.